# Laravel eloquent model query for `not null`

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been using Laravel for a project and using the Eloquent models to grab the model instances I need.

However, it doesn't look like there's a way to query for `not null` values.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models

Is there a way to do something like this, where I want to get all `Flight` models where the `ticket_id` is `not null`?

```
$flight = App\Flight::where('ticket_id', '!=', null);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this

```
$flight = App\Flight::whereNotNull('ticket_id')->get();
```

Comment: thks a lot, u saved me